# Ideal length of a cardio for someone who is losing weight

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, cardio

In a similar question the following is stated however I've read online that 30 minutes is better. Is there any conclusive study or research on the ideal length of a cardio for someone who is losing weight?

> Anywhere from 30 minutes to about an hour and a half is considered
>   healthy, as long as you aren't overworking yourself by doing this
>   routine more than every other day.

I do cardio in the morning with empty stomach due to work. I find it very difficult to go on after 30 mins.

I'm 100kg m 23. HR: 160. Elliptical cycle level 8/8. Daily intake: 1500. BMR: 1700. Desk job and 30 mins cardio everyday.

Comment: You might want to add some more details about your weight, caloric intake, etc. if you want a specific answer, as it is hard to give an exact time that works for everyone without knowing any details. But read this, it might help you have a better understanding on what works best for cardio: http://livehealthy.chron.com/length-vs-intensity-cardio-2503.html

Answer (score 1):

Cardio can be good, but I'd recommend doing weights a few times a week aswell since you have a desk job and are inactive for most of the day.

Putting on more muscle will mean you're burning more calories throughout the day while at rest.

Weight training is also more fun than cardio on a machine in my opinion :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you can do 30 minutes of cardio every morning, that's perfectly fine, so long as you realize that your diet has to be aligned with your goals as well. It seems like you have that covered though.

Obviously, there is no way we can tell you that instead of 30 minutes, you should be doing 28 or 41 minutes, because we're all different, and even still, determining this number would require a copious amount of testing.

The most important thing about your cardio, is that you consistently find the motivation to do it. If, at some point, you start to feel that 30 minutes is a bit much, the usual reaction is "I don't want to do it". But in fact, a more reasonable reaction would be "I'll do 20 minutes instead".

There's a tip we give everyone; the ideal workout is the one you actually do. If a program makes you want to quit, change the program.

There are split opinions on the whole empty stomach cardio thing, so I won't go too much into that, but I've personally had success with it, so I'm *for* doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The length of your workout totally depends on your intensity.

If you are going for a light walk where you are talking to your friend at the same time then 30 minutes may not cut it for weight loss

You many need 45-to-90 minutes of cardio if the intensity is so low where you can still talk without much trouble but on the other hand...

if you do intervals or HIIT like [this HIIT fast weight loss workout here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrw1rcKHEGs) then you can get away with only 10-to-20min and lose just as much weight as someone doing 30+ minutes of a lower intensity

So the ideal length depends on how intense the workout is going to be and maybe also your current daily schedule. If your schedule is open then the 30-to-90 min may be fine but if not then you'll have no choice but to find some 10-20 HIIT workouts to force weight loss